# How to split a comma-separated string into a list of strings?

Tags: python, list

The input is something like: `"W,79,V,84,U,63,Y,54,X,91"`

Output should be: `[‘W’, ‘79’, ‘V’, ‘84’ , ‘U’, ‘63’, ‘Y’, ‘54’, ‘X’, ‘91’]`

but my code is filled with comma.

```
a1 = list(input())
print(a1)
```

my output is `['W', ',', '7', '9', ',', 'V', ',', '8', '4', ',', 'U', ',', '6', '3', ',', 'Y', ',', '5', '4', ',', 'X', ',', '9', '1']`

How do I remove the commas?
Note :cant use build in functions except  `input()`, `split()`, `list.append()`, `len(list)`, `range()`, `print()`

Comment: `a1 = input().split(',')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to split the input using `input().split(',')`.

```py
a1=input().split(',')
print(a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

@MarcSances answered your question.
But if you just want to remove the commas from the list just use this

```
a1 = [x for x in list(input()) if x != ',']
print(a1)
```

Or do it in 3 lines

```
user_input = list(input())
a1 = [x for x in user_input if x != ',']
print(a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best way to do this in python**

```
#Devil
your_input = input()
lst = your_input.split(",")
print("output:", lst)
# output : ['W', '79', 'V', '84', 'U', '63', 'Y', '54', 'X', '91']
```